# .lib and .dll during deployment of C++ code to Github

Tags: c++, dll

I understand that .lib is static library linking and .dll is dynamic. This means that when .exe is produced, .lib does not need to be around for .exe to work. However, .dll need to be put in the correct relative path for .exe to reference and run.

My question is for .lib. When uploading the source code to Github, do I include .lib file in the project folder as well? What is the best practice in doing so?

Most of the tutorial that shows how to install library makes us link .lib file to its original folder and move .dll file into the working project folder. So should I move .lib file into my project folder as well? If I don't do that, it means the person that download my source code will have to go find the corresponding .lib file to link and compile right?

Comment: Your question title is about deployment. Your question body is about uploading stuff to github. What is it? Deployment or source management?

Comment: "If I don't do that, it means the person that download my source code will have to go find the corresponding .lib file to link and compile right?" If they're compiling your code, they can acquire the library for themselves (e.g. through their environment's package manager) and compile or link to it as part of their build process. It's not your responsibility to distribute someone else's library.

Comment: Not entirely true. True that you don't need the lib at runtime, but you can use a .lib to describe the DLL that will be required at runtime. The lib might just contain linkage information for a DLL and not the library itself.

Comment: @underscore_d I agree. I am a nodejs programmer and it is so easy for for nodejs program as it has package.json and you can just run npm install. But this is c++. I myself find it extremely difficult to download and build library and link to my project. I want to save other this pain and suffering : ) Or save my future self! I just want to be able to download the code, open with Visual Studio and compile!

Comment: @Zanko I get what you mean, but there are drawbacks to providing everything on a plate. For example, they won't get the benefit of updates, patches, etc provided by their environment. I guess this is less of an issue on Windows, where DLL Hell is the norm, and there are so many hassles with dynamically linking to cross-platform stuff built with MSYS2, Cygwin, etc that it often seems easier just to take a snapshot of all the DLLs into a redistributable bundle...which is what I'd do for distributing as a binary. Distributing half and half is a bit different/odd. Why not just provide a final exe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My own "IMHO answer" would be: *"GitHub is concerned with **source** code."* Therefore, I would not suggest including a binary `.lib` file there. And, I probably also would not put a binary `.dll` file there, either.

To clarify the difference between the two files ...

A `.lib` file is a library of object-code, resulting from previous compiles, that can now be referenced by the linker. The linker will *choose* whatever it needs, then *copy* these items out of the library into whatever it may be building at the time.

A `.dll` is a *dynamic* library ... "dynamic" in the sense that *applications* (and, other DLLs ...) can load it and unload it at runtime. *(The Windows program-launcher also automatically loads any DLLs that are directly or indirectly referenced by anything it is launching.)*

`.dll`'s are "all or nothing." You load them in their entirety, at *run*time.  `.lib`'s, by contrast, are true *libraries,* which are used only by the linker.

=== **Edit:** And the *next* Answer, IMHO, "nailed it."

Comment: My main intention is to maybe allow the user that download my code to easily compile my project into .exe. By not including .lib and .dll does that mean I will send them down on a hunt of compatibale .lib .dll that can be used with my code? Thank you for answering by the way!

Comment: *Hmmmm.....* Not an easy question *(and I beg other SO-participants to please chime-in here!),* but offhand I would suggest that you should include the source-code to everything, including all libraries, then provide **very** specific instructions on how to build the thing. ### I suggest that you (and I) should wait a day or two for other comments and answers to accumulate. "Let's all wait for a *consensus."*

Comment: @MikeRobinson Very specific instructions are nice but can't hold a candle to a comprehensive build script produced by the likes of `autoconf`, which checks and configures everything required on the environment it finds itself in. Zanko, depending on licence, might not be required - or advisable - to include local source for 3rd-party libraries. Anyway, in this case, it's not clear why they don't just provide the final executable. They want to make it easy, right? Why only go halfway by providing the core as source but some library compiled? (This doesn't preclude providing source separately.)

Comment: @underscore_d I will provide the final .exe and dlls in my release page on Github. But on the source code page I am just wondering if it would be convenient to just has everything ready for compiling. Maybe I got slightly scared, I just successfully installed libcurl and spent many hours researching/reading. I want to save my future self from these complication if I want to recompile my program. But on second taught, it might get easier for me as time goes by and installing lib might not be as scary as it seems...

Comment: @Zanko Have you tried MSYS2+MinGW? It's a tracking port of Cygwin that enables using Linux-style toolchains to achieve, crucially, native compiling of programs against Win32 (rather than the emulated POSIX environment of Cygwin) - and has a package manager (`pacman` from Arch Linux) with a wide variety of programs/libraries ready to use and updated often. Like a Linux build environment but on/for Windows. Compiling libraries as a beginner can be a nightmare, yeah, but (A) it gets easier, and (B) don't do it if someone else already maintains them for you! I have no affiliation, etc.

Comment: @underscore_d thank you for suggesting! I will read it up! Just minor questions. 1) Can it be used with Visual Studio 2015? 2) Must I be running on Linux?

Comment: @Zanko (1) Hmm, it's more targeted at providing a complete and self-contained build system, and I don't know whether you'll be able to link your VS-compiled programs with its binary packages from its own compiler (MinGW, a port of GCC)... but it's always worth trying! (2) MSYS2 is a Windows suite that provides a _Linux-like_ build environment and supporting packages; it doesn't run on Linux (although for those who do, cross-compilers are available too).

Answer (score 6):

Git repos are about code, and you should not have binaries in your git repos.

However, github has a feature called [releases](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software) which allows you to upload binary assets alongside your tagged source releases.

You can add your compiled libraries there.

Comment: Thanks! On a sidenote, how would you deal with code that reference image or sound? Should those binary be included as well?

Comment: @Zanko I believe so. Include whatever you need to make it a working package.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is really about dependency management.  Irrelevant of .lib or .dll, these are just different sorts of dependencies.  Your question is if someone clones my repository, how can they build it?

The answer is you need a build script, makefile, rakefile, jake file, etc... something that the user can run to do the build.  For instances this could be a README which says: "go download the files you need from website X".  Alternatively you can do as you suggested an put the necessary dependencies within your repository.  Legally this isn't always permitted as it is considered "redistribution".  The best approach is to use some sort of dependency management.  Depending on the language you are using there are different dependency management solutions.  I would recommend only using libraries (.dll, .lib, .tar, .*) from public dependency repositories.

In Java, the recommended approach is using something called maven.  Ruby has gems, node.js has npm packages.  This is nothing more than a file with a list of dependencies, and a tool which knows how to retrieve them.  To build my libraries it is as simple as running
`npm install && node make.js`  which says run the nodejs package manager (dependency manager) to download all the necessary files, and then run the build script.

For C++ it could be something like `make install && make` which would require a makefile you configure to say these are the things which need to happen before the project can be built.

Personally C++ has poor dependency management, but that may turn out some negative responses, I'll just say dependency management in C/C++ isn't my favorite and for mostly internal software or small use I would still with committing the lib with your code.  If there is a public repository which contains your lib files you could always generate a makefile/Cmake to `curl` or `wget` as part of the build process before you call gcc compiler.